# Windows 7 USB drivers corrupted, can't use mouse or keyboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

I recently rearranged the connections of the USB hubs on my motherboard and when I next booted Windows 7 it seemed to corrupt my USB driver store. When the computer starts the keyboard and mouse are both completely functional pre-Windows, but by the time I make it to the welcome screen one or both devices are disabled.

I can say definitively that these devices work; the problem is that Windows 7 has corrupted drivers. Because I am unable to operate the keyboard or mouse within Windows, I am unable to resolve the problem directly.

**What I've Tried**

- Changed the ports used for the mouse and keyboard.

  - Works sometimes, but as soon as Windows tries to install the drivers for the new ports, both devices stop working
- Under the system startup repair utility (where the keyboard and mouse both work), tried to revert to a prior restore point.

  - Failed outright regardless of which restore point I select (generic error). Not sure why...
- Also using system startup repair, mounted the HKLM\SYSTEM hive from C:\windows\system32\config into regedit and deleted all of the driver registers from the USB and Keyboard driver classes

  - Worked at first, until Windows reinstalled the corrupted drivers

At this point the only other thing I can think of is reinstalling Windows, but I'm trying to avoid that at all costs. Any advice?

Comment: Check the `windows\inf` directory for `usb.inf` and `usbport.inf`.

Comment: Depending on how you arranged your USB devices, you may no have enough energy to power them on the USB ports after rearranging them

Comment: You should be able to use the keyboard/mouse in safe mode, or, better yet, by remote controlling your machine via remote desktop.

Answer (score 1):

From an elevated command prompt, run `sfc /scannow.

sfc is the System File Checker utility included in Windows. When run with /scannow option, System File Checker verifies system files are in place and are not corrupted.

Comment: you might want to mention what sfc does...

Comment: On my system, this open and closes a prompt immediately. Nothing else. Hopefully that means I'm fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an external keyboard and download Synaptics pointing device. It replaces your old touchpad driver and is a lot smoother, then try to update the drivers for the laptop's actual keyboard. Hopefully at least one of the usbs will work. Either way, I hope you find the answer you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Boot into safe mode (with networking).

From Device Manager, remove the USB drivers.

Scan for changes.

Reboot into Windows.